# jQuery Form Validation plugin with multiple rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQueryValidation plugin. **Problem**: I would like to use multiple pattern rules within for one input field. E.g.:

```
$("form").validate({
 rules: {
    "email": {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    "password": {
        required: true,
        pattern: /^[A-Za-z0-9\w]{4,20}/,
        pattern: /^[\d\w\xC4\xD6\xDC\xE4\xF6\xFC\xDF]*$/
    }
 }
});
```

**What happens**: the plugin tests only the second pattern rule. E.g. entering something like "tst" works (as this fulfils the seconds pattern) although it violates the first pattern rule.

As far as I understand the logic of rules in this plugin, all rules have to return TRUE in order to validate a form.

Comment: a javascript object can't have 2 identical keys, second instance will overwrite first. You will need to add your own method for second pattern or combine both into one regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the same `key:value` pair twice since the second instance will override the first.

You have a couple of options.

- Combine the two regex expressions into one.  One method will be declared with one error message.  So instead of using the `pattern` rule/method from the `additional-methods.js` file, you will create your own custom rule using the `.addMethod()` method.
- Instead of combining the regex patterns, use the `pattern` rule once and create a new second rule using `.addMethod()`.

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

---

I'd create a custom method dedicated to each regex pattern and give it a *semantically relevant name*, something like 'email', 'phone', 'alphanumeric', 'IP', etc.  (This is also the same way all the regex evaluated rules are handled internally by this plugin.)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("foo", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z0-9\w]{4,20}/.test(value);
}, "Your entered data is not foo");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("bar", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[\d\w\xC4\xD6\xDC\xE4\xF6\xFC\xDF]*$/.test(value);
}, "Your entered data is not bar");
```

Declared like this...

```
"password": {
    required: true,
    foo: true,
    bar: true
}
```