# JavaScript regex for multiple strings that is case insensitive (none literal notation)

Tags: javascript, regex

A [plugin](http://formvalidator.net/#default-validators_custom) allows me to use regular expressions for data validation like so when I check for a single string:

```
<input type="text" data-validation-regexp="^\s*[Rr][Ee][Dd]\s*$" data-validation="custom">
```

The regex takes this format because of the following reason: [Have HTML5's a inputs pattern attribute ignore case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524842/have-html5s-a-inputs-pattern-attribute-ignore-case/5525111#5525111)

The plugin states:

> This plugin also supports the attribute "pattern" by using the HTML5
>   module.

As stated by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

> **pattern** - A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. The pattern must match the entire value, not just some
>   subset. Use the title attribute to describe the pattern to help the
>   user. This attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is
>   text, search, tel, url, email or password; otherwise it is ignored.
>   **The regular expression language is the same as JavaScript's**. The
>   pattern is not surrounded by forward slashes.

This regular expression in the `data-validation-regexp` attribute is an alternative to its literal notation/format which is `/red/i`

This raises the question are there any alternative ways to write:

```
/(rot|rouge|red|rojo)/i
```

I want to check for the strings rot, rouge, red or rojo. However **not** in literal notation/format while allowing for case insensitivity and space either side of the string. So if either of those strings are present then the regular expression 'passes'. (I am struggling to implement this after multiple experiments and would greatly appreciate the help).

When tested on https://regex101.com the regex `/(rot|rouge|red|rojo)/i` works in PCRE (PHP), but I need to find a JavaScript alternative and there must be some way to do this possibly using the OR operator.

Comment: use the inline modifier `(?i)`

Comment: How would I implement that in none literal notation please for the case described above?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20829713/29157

Comment: Isn't that a different plugin?

Comment: Do you mean a *constructor* notation like `var rx = RegExp("(rot|rouge|red|rojo)", "i")`? There are only 2 notations in JS regex: regex literal and constructor.

Comment: I mean that the plugin in use does not support this format with modifiers '/(rot|rouge|red|rojo)/i' so can I find a workaround? If the plugin doesn't support literal notation, should I attempt to create a variable like you are describing using vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: I think you need to write a [custom validator](http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2008/10/starting-with-jquery-how-to-write.html).

Comment: Could I call that variable 'rx' somehow into the 'data-validation-regexp' attribute with constructor notation or is that not possible?

Comment: No, I do not believe this is possible. Just check the value with JS code, inside a function.